# Issue in creating mysqldump of few tables with few entries from database

Tags: mysql

I am having an issue in creating a MySQL dump of few entries from the database.

I am importing only a few tables below is the query I'm running:

```
mysqldump -q -hlocalhost -udbuser -pdbpassword dbname
mdc_reports_product_stat mdc_reports_visitor_seance_info   
mdc_reports_visitor_seances mdc_reports_visitor_info 
mdc_reports_crawlers_visits 
--opt 
--where="1 limit 100" > Small_Reports_DBdump
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Reformatted code so all code is visible.

Answer (score 0):

In where clause you need to put all condition like user_id=1 or user_id>1 and according to man mysqldump options is going before db and tables, so:

```
mysqldump -q -hlocalhost -udbuser -pdbpassword --opt --where="1=1 limit 100" dbname mdc_reports_product_stat mdc_reports_visitor_seance_info mdc_reports_visitor_seances mdc_reports_visitor_info mdc_reports_crawlers_visits  > Small_Reports_DBdump
```

Comment: Can you dump without opts?